# Why doesn't Restkit parse correctly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

Why doesn't Restkit parse correctly?

Here my delegate call:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object {
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objectLoader.response.body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    RKObjectMapping *rm = objectLoader.objectMapping;

    NSLog(@"%@",s);
    NSLog(@"%@",rm);
    NSLog(@"%@", object);

}
```

and here the output

```
 {"device_id": "4f75c887e45b583e4f000004"}
RKObjectMapping class => ETDevice: keyPath mappings => (
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: device_token => secret",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: deivce_id => identifier"
)
(null)
```

any reason why it shouldn't work?
I don't think is a problem of the way I make the http request but anyway here is the code:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[objectManager sendObject:device delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {

    loader.serializationMapping = [[ETDevice objectMapper] inverseMapping];
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
    loader.resourcePath = @"/devices/init";
    loader.serializationMIMEType = @"application/json";
    loader.objectMapping = [ETDevice objectMapper];  
}];
```

btw I've also tried with:

```
{"device_id": "4f75c887e45b583e4f000004"}
{devices: {"device_id": "4f75c887e45b583e4f000004"}}
{devices: [{"device_id": "4f75c887e45b583e4f000004"}]}
```

please help, I'm timeboxing using restkit ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I got completely crazy for this. I've debugged almost all the stack in Restkit.
The bug was just:
"deivce_id" instead of "device_id".

I've learned a lot about restKit at least